# How do I update this web page every minute?

Tags: javascript, python

I have a web page with six div elements that need to be updated from the server once every minute on the minute.  I already have an open websocket which can pass data to the client from the server.  It might be easiest to send the data based upon a timer on  the server, but I have no problem with requesting the data from the server based on the client's clock, if that is better.  I am already requesting data from the server based upon keystrokes in another process.

div elements in style:

```
div.Out {
    position: fixed;
    top: 45px;
    left: 510px;
    width: 300px;
    font: bold 65px Lora;
    color: white;
}
div.In {
    position: fixed;
    top: 214px;
    left: 138px;
    width: 400px;
    font: bold 126px Lora;
    color: rgb(0,44,255);
}
div.Press {
    position: fixed;
    top: 400px;
    left: 585px;
    width: 250px;
    font: bold 29px Bookman;
    color: rgb(50,50,50);
}
div.Time {
    position: fixed;
    top: 42px;
    left: 178px;
    width: 250px;
    font: Bold 90px Arial Bold;
    color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
div.Date {
    position: fixed;
    top: 245px;
    left: 490px;
    width: 250px;
    font: Bold 45px Arial Bold;
    color: rgb(0,150,0);
}
div.Status {
        position: fixed;
        top: 350px;
        left: 160px;
        width: 250px;
        font: 50px Arial Bold;
}
```

Websocket code in body (Python):

```
print('<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">')
print('websocket = new WebSocket("ws://', host_ip, ':8000");', sep="")
print('document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {')
print('event.preventDefault();')
print('  const key = event.key; // "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowUp", or "ArrowDown"')
print('  switch (key) { // change to event.key to key to use the above variable')
print('    case "ArrowLeft":')
print('      // Left pressed')
print('      message = "Left";')
print('      websocket.send(message);')
print('      location.reload();')
print('      break;')
print('    case "ArrowRight":')
print('      // Right pressed')
print('      message = "Right";')
print('      websocket.send(message);')
print('      location.reload();')
print('      break;')
print('    case "ArrowUp":')
print('      // Up pressed')
print('      message = "Up";')
print('      websocket.send(message);')
print('      location.reload();')
print('      break;')
print('    case "ArrowDown":')
print('      // Down pressed')
print('      message = "Down";')
print('      websocket.send(message);')
print('      location.reload();')
print('      break;')
print('  }')
print('});')
print('websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };')
print('  function onOpen(evt)')
```

div elements in body:

```
print('<div class="Out">')
if FindCheck < 300:
    with open("/run/thermostat/outsideT","r") as f: # Get the Outside Temperature reading
        Tout = float(f.read())
    print('{0:5.1f}'.format(Tout),'<span style="font-size:44px">', ClassValues[0][LineValue[0]], '</span>', sep="")  # Show the outside temperature; note the inline style
else:
    print("----") # Stale data, display dashes
print('</div>')
print('<div class="In">')
if FindCheck < 300:
        with open("/run/thermostat/insideT","r") as f: # Get the Inside Temperature reading
                Tin = float(f.read())
        if LineValue[0] == 0:
                Tin = (Tin - 32) * 5 / 9
        print('{0:5.1f}'.format(Tin),'<span style="font-size:80px">', ClassValues[0][LineValue[0]], '</span>', sep="")  # Show the inside temperature; note the inline style
else:
        print("----") # Stale data, display dashes
print('</div>')

print('<div class="Press">')
if FindCheck < 300:
        with open("/run/thermostat/insideP","r") as f: # Get the Inside Pressure reading
                Pressure = float(f.read())
        print('{0:5.1f}'.format(Pressure), ClassValues[2][LineValue[0]]) # Print Barometric Pressure
else:
        print("----") # Stale data, display dashes
print('</div>')
print('<div class="Date">')
StringA=subprocess.check_output(["date", "+%a"])
StringA=StringA.decode("utf-8")
StringB=subprocess.check_output(["date", "+%b%e"])
StringB=StringB.decode("utf-8")
print(StringA.rstrip(), StringB.rstrip())
print('</div>')
if LineValue[4] == 0 or LineValue[4] == 2:  #  Auto or Cooling
    print('<div style="color:',bColor[5],'" class="Hot">Cool: {:02.1f}'.format(ClassValues[5]),'</div>', sep="")
if LineValue[4] == 0 or LineValue[4] == 1:  #  Auto or Heating
    print('<div style="color:',bColor[6],'" class="Cold">Heat: {:02.1f}'.format(ClassValues[6]),'</div>', sep="")
print('<div id="txt" Class="Time">', datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M'), '</div>')
```

The above writes everything to the web page, and I can force a full page update once every minute, but that is slow and does not work all that well.

Edit: I believe I have a partial answer.  By setting the div elements with an ID like so:

```
print('<div id="Out" class="Out">')
```

it appears I can later edit them by updating the innerHTML:

```
print('var Out = document.getElementById("Out");')
print('Out.innerHTML = "New Text";')
```

In some cases, however, I need to update the style elements as well as the text (which is why I originally included the CSS tag, but someone deleted it), and I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: It seems as if your question really doesn't need me (or anyone) to read through all your code examples. You have successful updates happening already based on client side events so all you're asking about is how to do timed updates. You prefer server side, though I can't see why, if server side decides to send data the client will likely ask if push permission should be granted to the server. Not 100% sure. I'd certainly favor client side timing and data pulling. Timing is not hard to do in [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp). And pulling data you do fine already.

Comment: I suppose the only reason I am leaning toward the server for the timing trigger is I am far more familiar with Python than Javascript.  If it is any way better to do it on the client side, I certainly will seek that code.  The main issue, here, is I don't know how to update the style in a div along with the text in that same div.  The point I was trying to make is I need to update the text in these divs, both attributes and information, based upon calculations done on the server.

Comment: The second piece of that is I need to change the text attributes internally to the updated div.  See the lines that look like:  print('{0:5.1f}'.format(Tin),'<span style="font-size:80px">', ClassValues[0][LineValue[0]], '</span>', sep="")  # Show the inside temperature; note the inline style

Comment: I have loads of examples in that space but none I'd say are wonderfully pedagogic.I would certainly time it in JavaScript, and suggest you leanr JavaScript well enough to do what you want. [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is perhaps the most ubiquitous library to make client side restyling and content alterations in response to server supplied data easy as pie, though stock JavaScript has come a long way to making that easier too. I'd simply be sending the data my client needs in [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) format back to the client which then adjusts styles and content.

Comment: As a rule, if you're writing HTML code in Python it's a suspiciously wrong thing to do. Not always, I sometimes end up there, but prudently and seldom and well justified. Most of the HTML and JavaScript your sending should be on the client page (in .html, .css and/or .js files) with data the client side needs to adjust displays sent to it in JSON (XML is also popular JSON more so I think because you can eval it in to JavaScript basically). Be very wary of writing HTML or Javascript server side and sending it. I have one site in ASP that does that and I hate it. Nightmare to maintain.

Comment: Can you please elaborate just a bit why you feel client-side timing is preferred?

Comment: I see. The web page is rather secondary to the real work being done on the server.  It's pretty simple and limited.  Very little, if any, maintenance will ever be done on the web page, as opposed to the data engines on the server, which are quite complex and massive by comparison.  Doing most of the web scripting in PHP would mean wrapping HTML inside PHP inside Python.

Comment: It's not the timing per se, so much as the decision making that's relevant. A client can request data from the server with no further ado and receive it back. But the minute the server decides it want to push some data to the client the client will often (typically) react by prompting the user with a notice that the server wants to do this, and asking for permission to trust it, and if most users are anything like this one, I almost always say "no". Not interested in your server pushing data my way at its behest.

Comment: Ah.  This is an embedded application, and the web page is automated.  It doesn't even have a keyboard or a mouse.

Comment: PHP is fine, so is Python, same general idea applies. I'd still try and keep a clean cut between the actual template (HTML, css), client side executing code (JavaScript) and server side executing code (PHP or Python). The general aim being server side sends minimal data needed for client side to take responsibility for rendering and layout. In fact any time spent learning what CSS can do for you is worthwhile if you're interested in layout and styling. I just took the trouble to learn CSS grids an wow - liberation!

Comment: If you can push data over the web socket without any client side concerns, then it doesn't matter at all really which side you do the timing on and push (server initiated send of data to client) and pull of data (client initiated request for data from server) are the same really. But I'd still try and keep HTML code in .HTML files, use CSS well and probably keep the server/client comms down to JSON myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution.  First, create a websocket relay in Python to relay messages to all clients (Note: this websocket handles more than just this function):

```
from simple_websocket_server import WebSocketServer, WebSocket

class Control(WebSocket):
    def handle(self):

        <Code to handle arrow presses from web page>

        string = pickle.loads(self.data)  # Get text list from data stream
        List = "Date Time StatusT StatusC Hot Cold Pressure TOutside TInside"  # List of valid keywords
        result = List.find(string[0])  # Make sure the first text element is a valid keyword
        if result != -1:
            MessageText = ",".join(string)
            for client in self.server.connections.values():
                client.send_message(MessageText)
server = WebSocketServer('', 8000, Control)
server.serve_forever()
```

Next, create a client, also in Python, to format and send the data to the websocket relay. Run every minute (or whatever):

```
import os, subprocess, pickle, time

def Transmit_Message(Key, String, *args):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    message = []
    message.append(Key)
    message.append(String)
    if args:
        for x in args:
            message.append(x)
    loop.run_until_complete(SendMessage(pickle.dumps(message)))

@asyncio.coroutine
def SendMessage(message):
    websocket = yield from websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8000')
    try:
        yield from websocket.send(message)
    finally:
        yield from websocket.close()

# Display the date
StringA = subprocess.check_output(["date", "+%a"])
StringA = StringA.decode("utf-8")
StringB = subprocess.check_output(["date", "+%b"])
StringB = StringB.decode("utf-8")
StringC = subprocess.check_output(["date", "+%e"])
StringC = StringC.decode("utf-8")
Date = StringA + StringB + StringC.rstrip()
transmit_Message("Date", Date)

# Display the time
Time = subprocess.check_output(["date", "+%H:%M"])
Time = Time.decode("utf-8")
transmit_Message("Time", Time.rstrip())

# Display the temperature
with open("/run/thermostat/outsideT","r") as f: # Get the Outside Temperature reading
    Tout = f.read()
Tout = float(Tout)
TOutside = '{:04.1f}'.format(Tout)
Scale = '&#8457;'  # Symbol for degrees F
transmit_Message("TOutside", TOutside, Scale)
```

On the web page, create a websocket in javascript to receive the values:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  const key = event.key; // "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowUp", or "ArrowDown"
  switch (key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
      message = "Left";
      websocket.send(message);
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      message = "Right";
      websocket.send(message);
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      message = "Up";
      websocket.send(message);
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      message = "Down";
      websocket.send(message);
  }
});

socket = "ws://" + window.location.hostname + ":8000"
websocket = new WebSocket(socket);

websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };

  function onOpen(evt) {
    document.getElementById("Connect").innerHTML = "Network: Connected";
  }
  function onClose(evt) {
           document.getElementById("Connect").innerHTML = "Network: Disconnected";
  }
  function onMessage(evt) {
    var msg = evt.data; // Index 0 is "TInside", "TOutside", "Pressure", "Date", or "Time"
    var array = msg.split(',');
    switch(array[0])
      case "TInside":
        document.getElementById("In").innerHTML = array[1];
        document.getElementById("InScale").innerHTML = array[2];
      break;
      case "TOutside":
        document.getElementById("Out").innerHTML = array[1];
        document.getElementById("OutScale").innerHTML = array[2];
      break;
      case "Pressure":
        document.getElementById("Press").innerHTML = array[1];
      break;
      case "Date":
        document.getElementById("Date").innerHTML = array[1];
      break;
      case "Time":
        document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = array[1];
      break;
    }
  }
</script>
```

JSON instead of pickle can be used if the data is more sophisticated or greater in extent.